# Returning exception message when the client expects octet-stream

Tags: spring-boot, rest, exception, http-headers, spring-webflux

I have an endpoint that returns back to us various data as `byte[]` wrapped in a `Resource`. The API is the following:
(Examples are made only to make the question understandable, not from a production-ready environment!)

```
@GetMapping(path = "/myResource/{id}"
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadData(@PathVariable("id") final String id) throws MyException;
```

In this project, we use error entities with message fields to describe the problems. These entities are handled by our `@ExceptionHandler` in the way below.

```
@ExceptionHandler({IOException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> ioExceptionHandler(IOException exception, WebRequest webRequest) {
    FaultDto dto = buildFaultDto(exception, webRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity(dto, HttpStatus.);
}
```

We usually serialize to a JSON (or XML) this `FaultDto` but I guess I can't do it when the client expects a `Resource` in a different way. What should be the proper way to send back this `FaultDto` in a response entity when the client expects `octet-stream` in the response?

Comment: Octet stream would be expected when the API is successful, In case when there is error then it has be some fallback error DTO which we are returning. I think whatever you are doing should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Do you know a "default" way to make the response octet-stream or what the client expects?